# VB.NET Find if file with unknown elements exist?

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, directory

I need to write an if function that finds if the a specific file exists, but the directory of the file contains unknown elements that may change from occasion to occasion. The code I have so far is:

```
If Dir(ProjectsFolder & ComboBox_ProjectType.Text & "\" & ProjectNumber & "\" & ProjectNumber & "_Rokasgramata\", ProjectNumber & "*User Manual*.pdf")(0) = "" Then
```

It returns an error and it's probably because of "*" What am I doing wrong? Could someone, please, help me with this one?

Comment: Sorry, but your question is not clear. Can you be more specific and provide example data? You have to explain your logic and show us which file contains "unknown elements" and what "unknown elements" means.

Comment: Unknown means it might be different each time, I mentioned that. In other codes of mine when I have an unknown element in the directory I use "*". The logic is also clear there either is or there is not a file I am looking for and I need to programmatically find if it does. Imagine you had a folder that may contain a numbered PDF files and you don't know which one it is, but you need to find if that directory has any pdf files regardless of it's number

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/programming/drives-directories-files/how-to-find-files-with-a-specific-pattern

Comment: Try `Directory.GetFiles(String, String)` where the first string is the path to search. The second string is the search pattern. This is found in System.IO

Comment: The code suggested is not correct. Directory is not declared and I have no idea what or how should I declare it. But I know of "io.Directory.GetFiles()" which returns an error that 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.' but I don't have no arrays

Comment: @Eduards the reason for "out of bounds" is probably due to trying get first item when it doesn't exist, You should check the length or simply use the `.Any()` extension method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with paths use `IO.Path.Combine`

Use that path to create a `New IO.DirectoryInfo(path)`

This object has `.Exists` property to ensure that the directory exists.

Finally use `.EnumerateFiles(ProjectNumber & "*User Manual*.pdf").Any()` To check if any such file exists.

Comment: And the full string would be?

Comment: @Eduards the strings are constructed from your parameters, or do you mean "full code"?

Comment: I mean full code, yeah :)

Answer (score 0):

I was very close and figured it out on my own

```
If Dir(ProjectsFolder & ComboBox_ProjectType.Text & "\" & ProjectNumber & "\" & ProjectNumber & "_Rokasgramata\" & ProjectNumber & "*User Manual*.pdf") = "" Then
```